# Uncaught Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Esto es lo que me marca al intentar insertar un dato:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Preguntas\insertarHistorial.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Preguntas\insertarHistorial.php on line 12

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php include("conexion.php"); if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){  if(isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['ida'])){
      $c=$_GET['c'];
      $ida=$_GET['ida'];

      $link=Conectarse();
      $resultado=mysqli_query($link,"insert into historial(idhistorial,calificacion,fk_idUsuario) values(null,'$c','$ida');") or die($link);

      //or die($link)

      if(mysqli_affected_rows($link)>0){
        print json_encode(array('estado'=>'1','mensaje'=>'Correcto'));
      }else
          print json_encode(array('estado'=>'2','mensaje'=>'Incorrecto'));
    } else
        print json_encode(array('estado'=>'3','mensaje'=>'Campos vacíos')); } ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 12 del archivo `insertarHistorial.php`?

Comment: esta es la linea 12 $resultado=mysqli_query($link,"insert into historial(calificacion,fk_idUsuario) values('$c','$ida');") or die($link);

Answer (score 0):

En tu código, `$link` no es una cadena, por tanto, no puedes intentar imprimirlo con `die()`, `echo` u otro, tal y como haces aquí:

```
  ... or die($link);
```

Te propondré un código en el cual, en caso de que la consulta falle, muestre un mensaje con el motivo del fallo, aunque no es recomendable mostrar al usuario mensajes de error internos. La práctica recomendada es implementar mensajes de error personalizados. Pero en fase de desarrollo se suelen mostrar mensajes internos para depurar mejor el código. Luego en producción implementas mensajes personalizados.

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){  
        if(isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['ida'])){
            /*
                Usaremos fusión de null para evitar problemas
                de "undefined index"
                Si usas PHP inferior a 7, debes cambiar fusión de null 
                por operadores ternarios
            */
                
            $c=$_GET['c'] ?? null;
            $ida=$_GET['ida'] ?? null;
            if ($ida && $c) {
                include("conexion.php"); 
                $link=Conectarse();
                if ($link) {
                    $sql="insert into historial(idhistorial,calificacion,fk_idUsuario) values(null,'$c','$ida')";
                    $resultado=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
                    if ($resultado) {
                        if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0) {
                            $outPut=array('estado'=>'1','mensaje'=>'Correcto');
                        } else {
                            $outPut=array('estado'=>'?','mensaje'=>'Cero filas insertadas');                            
                        }                       
                    } else {
                        $outPut=array('estado'=>'2','mensaje'=>sprintf('Error en la consulta: %s',mysqli_error($link));
                    }
                } else {
                    $outPut=array('estado'=>'?','mensaje'=>'Error en la conexión'); 
                }   
            } else {
                $outPut=array('estado'=>'3','mensaje'=>'Campos vacíos');
            }
    } else {
        $outPut=array('estado'=>'?','mensaje'=>'Método no permitido');          
    }
    echo json_encode($outPut);
?>
```

Si observas, en tu código había tres casos sin cubrir: la posibilidad de que no haya conexión, la posibilidad de que la consulta no registre ninguna fila afectada por ejemplo por registro duplicado, la posibilidad de que el método no sea `GET`. En el código he cubierto también esas tres posibilidades, poniendo en el estado he puesto `?`, lo puedes cambiar por un número, en el caso de que esos números representen algo en una presente o futura política de manejo de errores en tu programa.

Implementando este código, vas a tener en `$outPut`, lo que sea que haya ocurrido en cualquier punto del programa.

Comment: okey lo implementare muchas gracias